# Two spring banners in unit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have strange problem in my spring boot test.
When I run it there are 2 springs banners printed on console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.6)

Skipping auto-registration
Default master password will be used for encryption

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.6)

Skipping auto-registration
```

It looks like 2 contexts are loaded.
Then I open "Spring" tab I see there 2 elements:

```
MyApplication (autotedected)
MyApplication MVC  (autotedected)
```

My test class is like below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockMvcTestConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("mvcTest")
class AuthControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    . . .
}
```

MockMvcTestConfig looks like

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@MapperScan
@Profile("mvcTest")
public class MockMvcTestConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder embeddedDatabaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return embeddedDatabaseBuilder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase springLiquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase springLiquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        springLiquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        springLiquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/my.json");
        return springLiquibase;
    }
    ...
```

How is it possible? And there the problem can be?

Comment: Is this your only test class or do you have other tests with the `SpringBootTest` annotation?

Comment: By any chance have you included the surefire plugin in your build configuration?  Surefire will run tests in parallel if the `forkCount` parameter is set to a value higher than 1.

Comment: @dunni, Only this class has annotation SpringBootTest.

Comment: @lane.maxwell, No I don't use this plugin. Also I run only one test from this test class (not all tests)

Comment: My guess (corrected): you startup two contexts in one test (to same console.out) (so: `MockMvcTestConfig` or "structure of your code" to blame!;)

Comment: @xerx593, I added MockMvcTestConfig  content, but there is nothing criminal.

Comment: , no indeed: looks also legal/normal...then can it (only) be: "my application" and "my application mvc"  reside in same package (of same project)/scan each other!?

Comment: ..but only in test!? How do you distinguish (from cmd line/in deployed state), which to "run"?

Comment: @xerx593, I use Idea as my IDE, and there it is possible to run one test.
About same package... I can't find this, because I I don't have enough knowledge about Spring Boot

Comment: looks like: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33079 (fixed by 3.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` and also `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockMvcTestConfig.class})` and try to run.

Comment: If I remove AutoConfigureMockMvc  nothing is changed.
If I additionally remove ContextConfiguration there are also 2 spring boot banners, but I got error about ApplicationContextException